# Store API response body into a variable in Selenium using C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So, I'd like to be able to store the API response body into a variable or string after clicking a button that generates a report on my front end application. I know that there are other tools out there for testing APIs, and I know that its not something usually handled by front end automation testing, but the report component that my organisations application is using returns a  which is purely just an image element, that I can't drill into to verify the parameters that I've asked for in my report, are indeed the parameters on the report image. The API response body has this info, so hence my question. I've already looked heavily online to find the solution. I've experimented so far with IDevTools, and also INetwork interfaces, but I just cannot seem to figure out the right way of doing it. I think I need to initiate a network listener before the button is clicked, but I can't work out how to do it.

This is the latest snippet of code I've tried, but this still doesn't return anything.

```
IDevTools devTools = (IDevTools)driver;
DevToolsSession session = devTools.GetDevToolsSession();
session.Domains.Network.EnableNetwork();
            
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("report button")).Click();
           wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("chart")));

session.DevToolsEventReceived += Session_DevToolsEventReceived;
static void Session_DevToolsEventReceived(object? sender, DevToolsEventReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.EventData);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is initiate an API call fetch its data and do something. You will be able to get the API call response via `HttpClient`. Replicate the same request passing your URL to the API URL below check for the status code and assign the value of paylod accordingly. Refer the below code for more reference

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string apiUrl = "<your-api-url-here>";
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync(apiUrl).Result;  
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                Console.WriteLine("API Response Body: " + responseBody);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("API request failed with status code: " + response.StatusCode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It gave me a 401 unauthorised, but this is much closer than where I was. Is there a way I can dynamically fetch the api url?

Comment: Put it into you appsettings.json file.. Can you please mark it as the correct answer and give the answer an upvote. Appreciate it alot :-)